# How can I destroy point when it collides with player instead of bouncing when it collides

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to game in which player shoots in air and collects point by colliding with it. I want my player to destroy the point when it collides with it. But when the player collides with it player it just bounce off.

This is my PointCollection scripts

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PointColliection : MonoBehaviour
{
     
    private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Point"))
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    } 
}
```

This is my Player scripts

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    [HideInInspector] 
        public Rigidbody2D rb;
    [HideInInspector]
        public CircleCollider2D col;

    [HideInInspector] public Vector3 pos { get { return transform.position; } }

    void Awake ()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
        col = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D> ();
    }

    public void Push (Vector2 force)
    {
        rb.AddForce (force, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
    }

    public void ActivateRb ()
    {
        rb.isKinematic = false;
    }

    public void DesactivateRb ()
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        rb.angularVelocity = 0f;
        rb.isKinematic = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the OnTriggerEnter2d function but you say that the game object bounces of the player. It means you have not set the collider to trigger. Also you are checking for collision inside the point script, so the other collider's tag would be Player and not Point.

Or put this inside the player script

```
  private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Point"))
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Bro i can't vote anyone it shows at least 15 reputation to cast a vote.